# Any Security holes in this php code?

Tags: php, security, random, one-time-password

i found the structure of the following code on this very site, and i'm now using it, so i just want to know if there are any security holes that can be exploited from this code, if it can be improved or if at all there are any deprecated elements i shouldn't use.

i'll be using the following for OTP Code through SMS.

```
<?php
function randomCode(){
$alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
$Code = array();
$alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){
$n = rand(0, $alphaLength);
$Code[] = $alphabet[$n];
}
return implode($Code);// turn array into string
}
echo randomCode();
?>
```

*Beginner*

Comment: Where lol, pls fix it.

Comment: There is http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for it

Comment: You shouldn’t use neither `rand` nor `mt_rand` but `openssl_random_pseudo_bytes` or random sources like `/dev/urandom` if possible.

Answer (score 1):

**upd.**
I rewrote the code a bit:

```
function randomCode(){
    $alphabet = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    $Code = "";
    $alphaLength = strlen($alphabet) - 1;
    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++){
        $Code .= $alphabet[rand(0, $alphaLength)];
    }
    return $Code;
}
echo randomCode();
```

**upd2.**
This would be secure, if you block this code after 3 wrong attempts.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you should not use insecure random number generators for security purposes.

From http://php.net/manual/en/function.rand.php

> Caution This function does not generate cryptographically secure
>   values, and should not be used for cryptographic purposes. If you need
>   a cryptographically secure value, consider using
>   openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() instead.

This is because the `rand` will generate predictable values, the attacker only needs to figure out the seed used.

See here: [Predicting the output of PHP's rand()](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/76229/predicting-the-output-of-phps-rand)

Answer (score 0):

use more charecters like @ or # and lowercase letters in your $alphabet var.

Comment: Why? Won't the same attach used to generate the simple A-Z, 0-9 be used to generate those other charecters? Besides, those charecters are somehow taking time to type for some users. Ain't we looking for shorter typing time when typing passwords? Pls expatiate

Comment: come on... typing those chars are not really that time consuming, but if you think they really are, there is a rule: more security more difficulty.